# Python, Kivy, Buildozer: error using python-firebase/requests

Tags: android, python-2.7, firebase, kivy, buildozer

[Python = 2.7]

I recently started to use kivy (newest version) to develop an app for Android. For this I use buildozer (newest version) to create the apk file. Now everything works fine on my computer even using the python-firebase module. To send data to the Firebase online database. But when I want to use the Python module *python-firebase* (that is based on the module *requests*) on my phone the app crashes after it loads for a few seconds.

For now my requirements in the buildozer.spec are plyer and kivy. If I try to add requests to this list, I get the error:

```
# Install requirement requests in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --download-cache=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/notwaka/Desktop/Gps/.buildozer/applibs requests'
# Cwd /home/notwaka/Desktop/Gps/.buildozer

    Usage:   
      pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
      pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
      pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
      pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
      pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --download-cache
# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/notwaka/Desktop/Gps/.buildozer/applibs requests
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
```

Do I need to add requests to the requirements, since it is done in an example in the documentation of using buildozer? What can I do to make python-firebase working on my Android device? I have no knowledge about how to make a recipe and can't find any good documentation about this. Could making a recipe work? Has anyone tried to get Firebase working with Python on Android?

```
'# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph click cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer ffpyplayer_tito flask freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph itsdangerous jinja2 jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto markupsafe midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws werkzeug wokkel zeroconf zope
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/applibs
# Run 'bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && env"'
# Cwd /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer
LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8
XDG_VTNR=7
LC_ADDRESS=nl_NL.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/notwaka
SELINUX_INIT=YES
LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-wWFm7x/gpg:0:1
VTE_VERSION=3409
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8
WINDOWID=65011724
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1938
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-wWFm7x
GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
USER=notwaka
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LC_TELEPHONE=nl_NL.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-wWFm7x/ssh
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/venv
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/venv/bin:/home/notwaka/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/notwaka/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
ANDROIDAPI=19
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nl_NL.UTF-8
JOB=gnome-session
PWD=/home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1936
GDM_LANG=en_US
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8
ANDROIDNDK=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
PS1=(venv) 
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
PACKAGES_PATH=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/android/packages
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
HOME=/home/notwaka
SHLVL=2
XDG_SEAT=seat0
LANGUAGE=en_US
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=started starting
ANDROIDSDK=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
LOGNAME=notwaka
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-lqf94SPFU0
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
ANDROIDNDKVER=r9c
UPSTART_JOB=unity-settings-daemon
INSTANCE=Unity
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
LC_NAME=nl_NL.UTF-8
XAUTHORITY=/home/notwaka/.Xauthority
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
_=/usr/bin/env
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
# Install requirement pygments in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --download-cache=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/applibs pygments'
# Cwd /home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --download-cache
# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/notwaka/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/notwaka/Desktop/try/.buildozer/applibs pygments
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no such option: --download-cache

This reflects a bug in python-for-android that is now fixed. If you make buildozer re-download python-for-android, e.g. by deleting the .buildozer dir in your build directory, it should work.

You can also edit the current downloaded distribute.sh to remove the `--download-cache` option when calling pip.

Comment: I deleted the .buildozer folder and re-build it by buildozer android debug, but that fails. Also in the distribute.sh file there is nothing about the --download-cache. Every time when I add requests to the requirements it gives the same error and if I don't add it, the app won't start by using import requests. 

This is the only line in distribute.sh containing pip:
' debug "Install pure-python modules via pip in venv"
 try bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && env CC=/bin/false CXX=/bin/false PYTHONPATH= pip install --target '$SITEPACKAGES_PATH' -r requirements.txt"'

Comment: It still fails with the same `--download-cache` error?

Comment: Yes. Could it be that the standard python version 2.7.6 does not support this? Because I use the standard python + pip versions of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The problem is that it is not possible to either import 'requests' or 'python-firebase' without adding these to the requirements in buildozer.spec. Both modules are installed by pip, so that is the weird part...

Comment: The error you have is caused by python-for-android adding the (now unavailable) `--download-cache` option when it calls pip. I don't know how you're triggering the problem if your p4a is up to date and doesn't include that.

Comment: I downloaded kivy, buildozer and all the needed stuff. I just updated everything, but it still gives that error. What do you suggest to try now?

Also in the distribute.sh file that is in .buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android, there is only that one line of pip standard libraries.

Comment: I reinstalled everything and now I can import requests. But I actually want to import python-firebase. I installed python-firebase with: sudo pip install python-firebase. Now in the requirements I can add python-firebase and this also adds that to the applibs, but somehow I cant import firebase in my android app, because the app then doesnt work. Do you know why:?

It has something to do that it doesnt load in the multiprocessing lib.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue for Firebase working on python Kivy. See https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/pull/26

This is because multicore processing is not fully supported on Kivy, which is used by Firebase. This caused the crash on kivy Firebase apps.

I haven't tried the patch yet, but looking at the comments, Zkanda did good. This might be what you're looking for.

---

Alternatively, you can use json to download data from Firebase.

What I did to use Firebase was to use python's native Requests library to make a json call to Firebase, which they support with https.

```
import json, requests
url = "https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/some_database.json"
resp = requests.get(url = url, json = {'create':True})
data = resp.json()
```

In your buildozer.spec file, under the Requirements, include

```
requirements = kivy,requests,simplejson,openssl
```

openssl is to support https, simplejson is for json.

---

Comment: I spent significant amount of time making a successful json call from my kivy program.Although it worked from desktop,it didn't from my android when I created the apk using buildozer.Someone told me in kivy user forum that json being a native python library does't require to be mentioned in buildozer.spec requirements section,however here i see you using simplejson for json.Do you have a source that tells what all popular libraries are actually available to be used in buildozer and where is the list of such names.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggested solution when encountering a similar issue with pygments, and it didn't work for me either. I increased log levels and found that pygments was being downloaded to lib64/python on my distro, whereas pip was looking for lib/python.

It appears to be related to this pip issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3056

I added a setup.cfg file in the .buildozer folder for my app, containing:

```
[install]
install-purelib=$base/lib64/python
```

and my app now installs successfully.

Comment: Hmm, this also does not solve my issue. I edited the total error in the post, maybe you can take a look? @Henkelis

Comment: I see from your log that you are now trying to install pygments, so it looks as though you've added that to your buildozer spec. Can you change the log_level in the buildozer spec to 2 and re-run please, then post your output. I get the error you are showing until I add the setup.cfg file - have you added that?